# sending two variables using httpresponse

Tags: ajax, django

```
foo = t.render(// blah blah //)
bar = t1.render(// blah blah //)
```

How can I send both these variables using `HttpResponse.`

Comment: I think your are confused with [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) and [context rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JSON, XML, CSV or any other format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve, a single view can return only one `HttpResponse` afaik, because a single request can only have one response. But if you want to have foo and bar (which I guess are rendered parts of a page) as variables in another view, you can add them to a regular `render_to_reponse`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('template.html', { 'foo': foo, 'bar': bar }, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

I guess this could be usefull if you have ajax requests/responses, this way you have easy access to newly rendered parts of a page.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("foo",foo);
json.put("bar",bar);
json.put()... and so on....
```